# Can't Scrape Attribute of <Input> from Sibling Element

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

I am trying to scrape some data using Symfony2, Goutte, and DomCrawler. I have a tricky situation where I need to get a value of an attribute inside a `<td>`.

Working section:

```
    $query = "//td[normalize-space(text()) = 'Event Title']/following-sibling::td[1]";
    $crawler->filterXPath($query)->each(function($crawler, $i) {
        echo $crawler->text();// . $i . PHP_EOL;
    });


<tr>
    <td>Event Title</td> 
    <td>the title is here</td> 
</tr>
```

well, now it's:

```
<tr>
    <td>Event Title</td> 
    <td><input value="thisiswhatIneed"></td> 
</tr>
```

And I'm trying to change the selector

```
$query = "//td[normalize-space(text()) = 'Presenter']/following-sibling::td[1]/input[value]";
```

Any idea how to continue to traverse the  so that I can access the `<input>` in order to get what it's attribute value="" is?

Comment: Shot in the dark. Is there a `next::input[value]` type of selector?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I tac it on. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `value` is an `input`'s attribute, you need slghtly change your xpath query:

```
$query = "//td[normalize-space(text()) = 'Presenter']/following-sibling::td[1]/input/@value";
```

See example [here](https://webscraping.pro/example-xpath/).

Comment: Awesome, that worked wonderfully! Just added the `/input/@value` on to the end and it correctly, found what I was looking for. Thanks again!